# Assign values (1 to N) for similar rows in a dataframe Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df:

| Name | Place | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | NY | 15 |
| Jack | London | 27 |
| John | Paris | 5 |
| Bill | Sydney | 3 |
| Bob | NY | 39 |
| Jack | London | 9 |
| Bob | NY | 2 |
| Dave | NY | 7 |

I need to assign an incremental value (from 1 to N) for each row which has the same name and place (price can be different).

df_out:

| Name | Place | Price | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | NY | 15 | 1 |
| Jack | London | 27 | 1 |
| John | Paris | 5 | 1 |
| Bill | Sydney | 3 | 1 |
| Bob | NY | 39 | 2 |
| Jack | London | 9 | 2 |
| Bob | NY | 2 | 3 |
| Dave | NY | 7 | 1 |

I could do this by sorting the dataframe (on Name and Place) and then iteratively checking if they match between two consecutive rows. Is there a smarter/faster pandas way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a grouped (on Name, Place) cumulative count and add 1 as it starts from 0:

```
df['Value'] = df.groupby(['Name','Place']).cumcount().add(1)
```

prints:

```
   Name   Place  Price  Value
0   Bob      NY     15      1
1  Jack  London     27      1
2  John   Paris      5      1
3  Bill  Sydney      3      1
4   Bob      NY     39      2
5  Jack  London      9      2
6   Bob      NY      2      3
7  Dave      NY      7      1
```

Comment: Can you convert answer to comunity wiki?

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I can remove it though because it's probably a dupe

Comment: Check checkbox in right side under question if click in `Edit`.